# Text-align center not working for some reason?

Tags: html, css, centering

I can't seem to get my text to align center. It works fine vertically but the text-align seems to be influenced by something.

It's the "Autorondreis" text in the header(main image on top) of this project:

[Example](http://rondreizen.ravenwebdesign.nl/reissoorten-single.php)

The h1 element with the .center-text class that I'm trying to center vertically and horizontally:

```
position: relative;
top: 50%;
-moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
-ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
transform: translateY(-50%);
text-align: center;
display: block;
color: white;
text-shadow: 0 1px 5px grey;
```

Could somebody take a look and help me figure out why it's not centering horizontally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add style `clear:both` to 2 elements i.e. `h1` tag with class `center-text` and `nav` tag with class `navigation-menu`

Hence, your updated css will be like following

```
.navigation-menu {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    clear: both;
}

.center-text {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 5px grey;
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is being centered to it's **parent** div.

try doing this:

```
body > #YourDiv
{ 
position: relative;
top: 50%;
-moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
-ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
transform: translateY(-50%);
text-align: center;
display: inline; <---Changed to inline
color: white; 
text-shadow: 0 1px 5px grey;
}
```

Let me know what results you achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

adjust your h1 tag to

```
h1{width:100%;}
```

Then your h1 `class="center-text"` should be central.

Comment: Does't work i'm afraid. Besides that it's already set as a block element and has 100% width already. Text-align does seem to do something when you try it with the left and right attributes but it only moves like 50 px on either side strangely. Thanks for taking a look though.

Answer (score 1):

use these css only and they will work, I have tried with my Firefox code inspector and its working -

```
.center-text {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%; /* added this line and changed the next four lines */
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block; /* changed this line */
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 5px grey;
    clear: both;
}
```